# gstreamer: no element "vp8enc"

Tags: archlinux, gstreamer, vp8

I am trying to follow this [simple example](http://delog.wordpress.com/2011/04/14/stream-webm-video-over-rtp-with-gstreamer/) to stream WebM VP8 video over RTP.

I am runinng Arch linux 64 bits, and I have compiled and installed the gstreamer version they talk about (i.e. the git version) and I followed [these instructions](http://delog.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/live-webm-video-streaming-with-flumotion/).

From what I understand, building from the git repo bilds gstreamer-1.0 so this is what I have.

I have `GST_PLUGIN_PATH` and `GST_PLUGIN_SYSTEM_PATH` point to /home/nschoe/usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0 (I have installed this gstreamer-1.0 completely in my home directory).

When I tried the command `gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc ! vp8enc ! rtpvp8pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=9001` I get the error :

`GST_PIPELINE ./grammar.y:687:priv_gst_parse_yyparse: no element "vp8enc"`

After [some researches](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-plugin-vpx.html), I found that vp8enc should be in gst-plugins-good, which I have installed.

But when I run `gst-inspect-1.0 -a | grep -i gst-plugins-good | grep -i vp8` I got :

`rtpvp8depay:   Source module            gst-plugins-good
rtpvp8pay:   Source module            gst-plugins-good`

So I don't understand why I don't have vp8enc and vp8dec. Besides, when I run `locate vpx.so` I have the following results (truncated to relevant results) :

`/home/nschoe/usr/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstvpx.so
/usr/lib/libvpx.so`

The former most lijkely comes from the gst-plugins-good that I have cloned from git and installed in my home directory, the latter I have installed from the Arch linux pacman, because I thought it would solve my problem.

Can you tell me why I can't use that vp8enc plugin ?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I still don't know what happened, but actually it turned out vp8 seems to be handled by gstreamer-0.10 : I removed everything and installed gstreamer-0.10 from archlinux's package manager as well as good, bad and base plugins and I could play .webm file.

Somebody might want to know that gstreamer-0.10 can handle webm correctly.

Answer (score 2):

gstreamer 1.0 can also handle webm correctly, it was likely some issue with your setup. It is actually advised to stop using 0.10 as it is obsolete and unmaintained by the community.

Did gst-inspect-1.0 /path/to/your/gst/libgstvpx.so

actually list the elements for vpx?

Comment: So gstreamer-0.10 **is** actually considered obsolete ?

I'm happy to try switching to 1.0, but can we do everything that 0.10 allows us to do with 1.0 ? Is it fully compatible ?

Comment: Yes, gstreamer-1.0 is the recommended replacement for 0.10 and should be able to do everything 0.10 can do and more. If needed, new features can be requested in https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=GStreamer